# Is it possible to have a templated c++ class to generically implement interface T and forward all calls to wrapped object implementing T?

Tags: c++, templates, delegates, decorator, variadic-templates

Is it possible to have a templated c++ class that generically implements interface T and dynamically delegates calls to one or more wrapped objects that implement T?

As usual, best to use code to explain what I'm trying to do:

```
// There are many interfaces:
class Foo {
 public:
  virtual ... DoFoo(...);
  ...
}
class Bar {
 public:
  virtual ... DoBar(...);
  ...
}
class InterfaceN { ... }
...

// Each interface has multiple implementations:
class SimpleFoo : public Foo { ... }
class FancyFoo : public Foo { ... }
class SimpleBar : public Bar { ... }
class FancyBar : public Bar { ... }
class SimpleInterfaceN : public InterfaceN { ... }
class FancyInterfaceN : public InterfaceN { ... }
...

// There are many consumers of these interfaces:
class ConsumerA {
 public:
  ConsumerA(Foo foo, Bar bar, ...);
 ...
}
class ConsumerB { ... }  // uses Foo, Interface2, Interface5
class ConsumerC { ... }  // uses Bar, Interface2
...
```

Currently, all consumers are using simple implementations. I need to be able to dynamically switch between simple and fancy implementations without modifying the consumers and existing simple implementations. It doesn't matter what the mechanism is that swaps the implementations. I could modify all fancy implementations to take in a simple implementation object and then dynamically switch between using its own fancy implementation or delegate to the simple implementation in each interface method call (i.e. incorporate switching logic into implementations).

```
// For each interface, add switching logic to fancy implementation:
class FancyFoo : public Foo {
 public:
  FancyFoo(SimpleFoo* simple_foo, ...) override;
  ... DoFoo(...) override {
    if (use_fancy) {
      // fancy implementation
      ...
    } else {
      return simple_foo_->DoFoo(...);
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

Ideally, I prefer not to pollute implementations with unrelated switching logic, so, instead, I can do a third implementation which does the switching:

```
class FooSwitcher : public Foo {
 public:
  FooSwitcher(Foo* first_foo, Foo* second_foo) {
    active_foo_ = first_foo;
    inactive_foo_ = second_foo;
  }
  ... DoFoo(...) {
    return active_foo_->DoFoo(...);
  }
  void SwitchFoos() {
    swap(active_foo_, inactive_foo_);
  }
  ...
 private:
  Foo* active_foo_;
  Foo* inactive_foo_;
  ...
}
```

So finally, my question is... Is it possible to have a generic switcher class so that the switching logic is written once and can be reused for each interface that needs it?
Something like this:

```
template <typename T>
class Switcher : public T {
 public:
  Switcher(T first_impl, T second_impl) { ... }
  ***magic that forwards/delegates all calls to any T methods to active_impl_***
 private:
  T active_impl_;
  T inactive_impl_;
}
```

...and it would be used something like so:

```
ConsumerA consumer_a = new ConsumerA(
    Switcher<Foo>(simple_foo, fancy_foo),
    Switcher<Bar>(simple_bar, fancy_bar),
    ...);
```

Comment: I believe that what you want requires Reflection TS... which will hopefully arrive in C++23. Untill then consider either something simple or something you can regulate with SFINEA.

Comment: I am really having a hard time to find out what is so unusual or impossible in what you want to accomplish but I can not find one. Please elaborate

Comment: @AKL How can Switcher generically override all methods of T for any type T and pass everything to the wrapped T object (i.e. without having to explicitly list those methods)? Is that even possible in one of the current C++ versions?

Comment: @tomosius You can overload `operator->` to return a pointer to the active foo implementation.

Comment: @tomosius I updated my answer to include Super's suggestion too. Please take a look and let us know if you were looking for some thing else.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple (without considering extra factors) Switcher class template which might be what you are looking for:

```
template<typename first, typename second, typename base>
class Switcher{
public:
    Switcher(first& _first, second& _second):first_object(&_first), second_object(&_second), active(first_object){}
    void switch_them(){
        if(active == first_object) active = second_object;
        else active = first_object;
    }
    base* operator &()const{
        return active;
    }
    base* operator ->()const{
        return active;
    }
private:
    first* const first_object;
    second* const second_object;
    base* active;
};
```

Please note that as others suggested, although using address-of operator, `operator&`, is completely OK here, you can also use `operator ->` in order to achieve similar functionality. I suggest choosing only one of them in order to reserve the other for future normal usage.

In case of a simple Foo and its simple derivatives:

```
class Foo{
 public:
    virtual int DoFoo() = 0;
    virtual ~Foo(){}
};

class SimpleFoo:public Foo{
 public:
    int DoFoo(){
        return 0;
    }
};

class FancyFoo:public Foo{
 public:
    int DoFoo(){
        return 1;
    }
};
```

The simple usage becomes like:

```
int main() {
    Foo* foo_pointer;
    SimpleFoo simplefoo;
    FancyFoo fancyfoo;
    Switcher<SimpleFoo, FancyFoo, Foo> switcher(simplefoo, fancyfoo);
    foo_pointer = &switcher;
    std::cout << foo_pointer->DoFoo() << std::endl;
    std::cout << switcher->DoFoo() << std::endl;
    switcher.switch_them();
    foo_pointer = &switcher;
    std::cout << foo_pointer->DoFoo() << std::endl;
    std::cout << switcher->DoFoo() << std::endl;
    switcher.switch_them();
    foo_pointer = &switcher;
    std::cout << foo_pointer->DoFoo() << std::endl;
    std::cout << switcher->DoFoo() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And finally the simple result:

```
0
0
1
1
0
0
```

Of course you can add extra features that you may want to it.

Comment: It's late and I'm confused. Disregard my last comment.

Comment: Instead of overloading `operator&`, you can overload `operator->`. Would be easier to use. `switcher->DoFoo(); switcher.switch_them(); switcher->DoFoo();`.

Comment: Thanks, I was getting very confused finding out what the problem was. But I am really curious to know in what circumstances the problem that you were describing can occur.

Comment: @super you are right, ```operator ->``` can also be used. And I edited my answer to include your suggestion too. however according to   https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators , I could not find any legitimate problem with using ```operator &```.

Comment: It works too. Maybe worth noticing is that it's in my experience a very unusual overload, so it's more likely to cause confusion for someone looking at your code.

Comment: @AKL in the current example of this answer, Switcher does not implement Foo, so it seems I would not be able to pass it to ConsumerA constructor which requires Foo*.